# Angular 5: Assign value to value attribute

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to assign a value to the value attribute if value is present else assign a default value

Here is my html statement

```
<input matInput placeholder="{{item.title}}" name="{{item.name}}"  
      [value]="config[key][item.name]||item.default" 
      (change)="config[key][item.name]=$event.target.value"
      [type]="(item.type=='string' ? 'text': 'number')">
```

If `config[key][item.name]` value present then use `config[key][item.name]` and if value is not present or default key is not present then blank string.

I'm trying

```
[value]="config[key][item.name]||(item.default=='undefined' ? "": item.default)"
```

But above statement gives error

Comment: Put that logic in the component code, not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The correct sintax is:

```
[value]="config[key][item.name] != undefined ?config[key][item.name]:item.default"
```

Edit with plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/EbptZ3a53weXphYJ1d6Y?p=preview

However, the best way to achieve this is do logic on typescript file.